# Problem with space between title and figure

Tags: spacing, lyx

it is my first time that i use latex, in particular lyx. I have to make a very simple page with a title a figure and 3 authors, but something strange happens when i put the figure after the title: there is a very big space and i don't know why, i think that when i press enter lyx does not exit from the title, however i do not have any idea about how to solve it.

code:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}

\title{Requirements Analysis and Specifications Document}

\maketitle
\begin{figure}
\begin{centering}
\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{../Desktop/Logo_polimi_grande}
\par\end{centering}
\caption{Politecnico di Milano}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: Here the pdf created]

Comment: Don't use a figure enviroment. It is very bad. You can smuggle in the picture with `\author` or `\date` which is bad from another point of view. Do you want a custom title page?

Comment: Wait, is the image part f the title? Why does it get a caption?

Comment: I want only a simple page with the figure immediately after the title or the date, I do not understand why there is that big space, the problem I think is when I press enter lyx does not exit from title

Comment: The caption, is it important? Is your document just this one page?

Comment: this is only the first page I have another chapter to put

Comment: Is the captin important?

Comment: in that case no, but for the other figure yes I want to resolve that problem, so that it will neve happen again

Comment: In that case, use the following code and read up on what floats aare in LaTeX.

Comment: `\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}

\title{Requirements Analysis and Specifications Document}

\maketitle
\begin{center}
 \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
\end{center}
\clearpage

\end{document}
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beside solution provided by @Johannes_B in his comment try the following:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}

\title{Requirements Analysis and Specifications Document}

\maketitle
\begin{figure} 
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

to control the virtcal space in lyx or latex used:

put cruser between the title and the image,Ctrl+L then write:

```
\vspace{-5pt}
```

you can change 5 to any number.

if you let the number + you get Increase the virtical distance.

if you let the number - you get Decrease the virtical distance.

regatds

Comment: Not sure if it was the preferred way to do it, but the above definitely helped me out by reducing the space above a small title image inserted via a `\pretitle` section.